# OO programming - Variables as member or just in the header as globals?

Tags: c++, class

maybe it sounds stupid but I am not sure what is the best way to handle this:

I have a class that provides access to a certain Com Port for example. To use this you have to set up a buffer with information. this buffer is realized as a typedef. right now this typedef is located in the header file of the class but not in the class as a member. the difference is the way you can access this buffer (header file included).
As a class member:

```
CMyClass::MyBuffer MyBuf;
```

or just as a global located in the header:

```
MyBuffer MyBuf;
```

I have a couple of data I am not sure where to put, like some static vars that act as a unique identifer in the buffer. So we are talking about statics and typedefs here.

Technically, they belong to the class because without those you can not work with it. But accessing theses type with the class name and its scope operator is much longer.

Does it matter how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't avoid putting something in a class which belongs to a class just because you find it inconvinient to write the class scope each time you need to access it.

Comment: On the other hand, namespaces are also used for logically grouping classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the actual name you are using is somewhat more descriptive that `MyBuffer`.  Does the buffer in any way belong to the class, other than being used by it?  Does it somehow depend on being in that specific class, and would a typedef of the same description, put in a different class, behave any differently?  If another class needed something similar, would the same typedef do?

In my opinion, if you answered "no" to the above questions, the typedef does not belong in the class at all; it seems like it is only used by that class.  It makes more sense to keep it global, as you may have another class using that typedef, but would end up keeping the implication that `MyBuffer` is somehow specific to `CMyClass`.

Comment: well the buffer exist because of that class. think of UART for instance. what you need is a typedef struct that keeps baud-rate and payload. so everyone who wants to talk to this class needs to know this buffer since it's the only way to interface this class. So it could be used by many classes. but if there is no namespace or you don't put in the class there must not be another typedef having the same name.

Comment: Sure, the class may use the typedef (let's say it's a `std::vector<char>`), but that does not mean the typedef is somehow intrinsic to the class.  What if you later want to abstract that class away behind several different views, or have some class that creates a buffer of this kind.  It is possible that the typedef really belongs to the class, but I see no evidence for this from the question or clarifications -- it seems like it's just usage, which, in my opinion, should be non-member.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to put the class `CMyClass` and the `MyBuffer` into a relevant namespace and use the `using` directive. Example:

```
namespace MyNS {
   class CMyClass
   {
      // snip
   };

   typedef blah MyBuffer;
}

some_function()
{
   MyNS::CMyClass a;
   MyNS::MyBuffer b;
}

using namespace MyNS;

some_other_function()
{
    CMyClass a;
    MyBuffer b;
}
```

This could be a possible solution.